# Understanding Native American DNA at gedmatch.com?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, native-american, gedmatch.com

How come gedmatch.com shows my alleged Native American DNA, but ancestry.com, FTDNA.com and 23andme.com does not?

Does anyone know why that is?

What is the difference between gedmatch database and the others?

Comment: Can you give more explanation as to how gedmatch is identifying your DNA as Native American?

Comment: GedMatch goes into more depth. My American Indian showed up there! It allows you to do many test. I recommend up loading there no matter where you had your test done.